# Delay resharper from starting immediately when Visual Studio opens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

How can I disable resharper from starting immediately when I open Visual Studio. I'd like for it to wait until my project has loaded completely and then start. This is as it lags the UI out when starting VS.

If I can't enable a setting to do this, can I achieve this by writing an extension that toggles the resharper enable/suspend command?

Comment: You and the rest of the world too, also if you write such an extension, let me know about it

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no option to achieve this, you either use resharper or  disable it completely by going to Tools -> Options --->Resharper ---> Suspend.